# Android - Accessing JSON children from a URL

Tags: java, android, json

I'm in the process of converting my website to an Android app and one of the pages' data currently is populated via JSON in my website. The way it works is that the URL generates a different JSON data with the same structure based on the passed ID. I already have the logic for passing the ID to the URL. Now I want to read the data through Java code and parse the JSON children and its values in it.

I have a URL that leads to the JSON file in textual form, but I'm not sure how to go about reading the data from it and accessing the child nodes based on the JSON key.

So I guess what I'm asking is what is the usual approach for this procedure? I see a lot of different examples, but none of which are applicable to my problem.

Anyone have any suggestions as to how I should approach this?

Comment: you are asking for json parsing?

Comment: Yes, how do I retrieve the JSON from the URL and parse it into Java objects?

Comment: first you need to learn about jsonobjects and jsonarray or json parsing then you can use volley or retrofit network libraries.

Answer (score 0):

JSONObject = new JSONObject(yourjsonstring);

Now you have your Json Object...

If your Json start with array use this:

JSONArray = new JSONArray(yourjsonarray);

Answer (score 0):

You can use existing libraries to parse JSON, gson or Moshi are two solutions.

The way you go about parsing the JSON is as followed

First you need to make pojo's with the same structure as the JSON file.

then you can parse it to java code via the fromJSON() method, this will make new objects and fill it with the data from the JSON.

gson example for clarification:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Response response = gson.fromJson(jsonLine, Response.class);
```

where jsonLine = your json file and the Response.Class the pojo in which you want to json to load.

Now you have the JSON values as Java classes in response.

If you're using Retrofit and OkHTTP to perform the network calls i suggest you use Moshi as it's also from Square and claimed to work faster and better than gson. (if you want to know why you can leave a comment).

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're trying to do is this

on post execute method do the following

```
  @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

                String status = "";
                String message = "";
                String tag = "";
                String mail = "";
                try {

                    JSONObject jsonResult = new JSONObject(result);
                    status = jsonResult.optString("status");
                    message = jsonResult.optString("message");
                    tag = jsonResult.optString("tag");
                    mail = jsonResult.optString("mail");
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

of course your json array contains different keys
Just reolace them with yours